# Listen for specific grammar c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, speech-recognition, speech-synthesis

I'm currently writing a speech recognition program and I would like the program to execute something if I say a certain word.

For example, I want the speech synthesizer to respond with "hello" if what I said was from the Grammar class *greetingg*.

I know I could just use `e.Result.Text == "something" || e.Result.Text == "something else"` but I want to specify either a specific grammar or grammarbuild or choices list.

How could I go about doing this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Threading;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;



namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<string> jokelist = new List<string>();

    SpeechSynthesizer sfos = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    PromptBuilder pBuilder = new PromptBuilder();
    SpeechRecognitionEngine sRecognize = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));


    internal static Choices slist2 = new Choices (new string[] { "hello", "hi", "howdy", "good morning", "hey", "what's up", "wazzup", "good day", "morning", "sup", "yo", "long time no see", "farewell", "take care", "later", "peace" });


    internal static GrammarBuilder greetinggb = new GrammarBuilder(slist2);
    internal static Grammar greetingg = new Grammar(greetinggb);


    public void Form1_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        jokelist.Add("Why was six afraid of seven? Because seven eight nine.");
        jokelist.Add("I think you look good, ha-ha-ha-ha");


        sRecognize.RequestRecognizerUpdate();

        sRecognize.LoadGrammar(greetingg);

        sRecognize.SpeechRecognized += sRecognize_SpeechRecognized;
        sRecognize.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        sRecognize.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);



    }
    Boolean listening = false;

    public void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized (object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {


        SemanticValue semantics = e.Result.Semantics;
        RecognitionResult result = e.Result;


        if (listening)
        {

            if (from grammar greetingg)
            {
                sfos.Speak("hello");
                listening = false;
            }
            else if (e.Result.Text == "tell me a joke")
            {
                sfos.Speak("Sure.");
                sfos.Speak(jokelist[new Random().Next(jokelist.Count)]);
            }
            else if (e.Result.Confidence <= 0.79)
            {
                return;
            }
            else if (e.Result.Text == "sleep")
            {
                sfos.Speak("Okey then");
                listening = false;
                return;
            }
        }


        else
        {
            if (e.Result.Text == "wake up")
            {
                sfos.Speak("yes master ?");
                listening = true;
            }
            else
                return;
        }
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + " " + e.Result.Text.ToString();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The [RecognitionResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.recognitionresult(v=vs.110).aspx) class has a property [Grammar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.recognizedphrase.grammar(v=vs.110).aspx) that the speech recognizer used to return the result. You could use this property to check which Grammar class was used.

The MSDN documentation is good resource when you're looking for stuff like this, it's loaded with examples.

```
public void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized (object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{

    SemanticValue semantics = e.Result.Semantics;
    RecognitionResult result = e.Result;

    if (listening)
    {
        if (result.Grammar.Equals(greetingg))
        {
            sfos.Speak("hello");
        }
        else if (e.Result.Text == "tell me a joke")
        {
            chip.Speak("Sure.");
            chip.Speak(jokelist[new Random().Next(jokelist.Count)]);
        }
    }
}
```

Another issue I see is that you're not setting the `listening` variable to true when once you start listening.

Add `listening = true;` after the `sRecognize.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple)` call.

Comment: For some reason, this solution doesn't work (at least to me). The grammars I'm using are a bit complex though. Is there no way to check if a recognized text is inside one possible combination of a certain grammar?